# Dimension of the restricted representation

Tags: representation-theory

My definition of restriction is: Let $H < G$, $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$. The restriction of $\rho$ to $H$, $\rho: H \rightarrow GL(V)$. Its character is
$$Res_H\chi(h)=\chi(h) \ \ \forall h \in H$$

Below this definition I have that $\dim Res_H \rho= \dim \rho$. This is stated without proof but to me this does seem obvious at all as I would have thought the restriction would have a smaller dimension.

Comment: Isn't the restriction still a homomorphism to the exact same general linear group? Isn't that all that determines the dimension?

Comment: I was not aware that it was just that

Comment: The vector space $V$ itself did not change at all, and its dimension is what is meant by the dimension of the representation.